# A random only makes the thing thats supposed to move in a diagonal line?

Tags: c#, button, random

I was making a button move by the click of it, and heres my code:

```
button1.location = new Point(new Random().Next(10, 385), new Random().Next(10, 385));
```

But that only seems to move the button in a diagonal line. Please help. Thanks

Comment: `r = new Random();. ...location = new Point(r.next(10,385), r.next(10,385))`. use a SINGLE random object

Answer (score 6):

Two Randoms created in a very short time (like in your code) will return a deterministic value. This is because in that time the seed values will not differ.

You should create a Random before and reuse it:

```
var random = new Random();
button1.location = new Point(random.Next(10, 385), random.Next(10, 385));
```